# Rearranging absolute values (limit proof)

Tags: limits, absolute-value

My textbook ends a proof with the following:

$|x-9| \over \sqrt(x) + 3$ < $\epsilon$

can be rearranged to conclude:

|$x-9 \over \sqrt(x) -3$ - 6| < $\epsilon$

However, I don't understand how the rearrangement of the absolute values works. How is this reasoned out explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

Observe $|x - 9| = (\sqrt{x} + 3)(\sqrt{x} - 3)$.

Cancelling in the first inequality from your post, we have:

$|\sqrt{x} - 3 |< \epsilon$.

Note the latter inequality in your post says, after cancellation, that

$|\sqrt{x} + 3 - 6| < \epsilon$, i.e., $|\sqrt{x} - 3 |< \epsilon$.

This gives all the necessary pieces.

We can now alter the order slightly to make it a cleaner proof.

---

**Proof:**

Cancelling in the initial inequality, we have

$|\sqrt{x} - 3 |< \epsilon$, i.e., $|(\sqrt{x} + 3) - 6 |< \epsilon$, which is equivalent to the latter inequality. **QED**.